# validation $_GET request

Tags: php, validation, security

### SERVER1(80.181.155.138)

Java Script

```
window.open("http://91.221.23.2?user_uid=123456789"'_blank');
```

### SERVER2(91.221.23.2)

```
$use_uid=$_GET["user_uid"];
checkUser( $use_uid);//connect to mysql SERVER1(80.181.155.138) and check user and permision
```

### Question:

if one person sniff packet between server1 and server2 and send request(`http://91.221.23.2?user_uid=123456789`)
how can validation this request?
i wanted share `c:\windows\tem` and use $_SESSION for send user_uid but i think this is not true.

how can we understand that one request is from validate source or invalid resource?

sorry for poor language:(

Comment: Study OAuth and you may get your solution

Comment: Define "validate source". What exactly is a "valid source" and what isn't?

Comment: validate source is request from `80.181.155.138`,how can get ip sender of request?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably misunderstanding something. Your server 80.181.155.138 is *serving a website* which contains this Javascript code. Any visitor, say, me on my computer at IP 1.2.3.4, will visit that site. My browser then executes that Javascript code and makes a request to 91.221.23.2. The request will come from 1.2.3.4. The server at 80.181.155.138 is completely irrelevant in this scenario.

In essence, 91.221.23.2 offers a *public API* which anyone can access; anyone *needs* to be able to access. You cannot limit this to "valid sources".

There are 3-way-handshake authentication schemes, for example OAuth. Investigate whether this is for you. You first need to understand the above described reality of your situation though.

Comment: ok,if i send  `$checker=md5(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))`  with user_uid and check this md5 on the destination?this is right?

Comment: Hardly, no. It's unclear what exactly the security requirements are in your case here, so I can't really say anything about it. But sending a hash of a date is no security.